# Comma separated list using angular ngfor and ngif

Tags: angular

I have a comma separated list that displays an array of four items.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
item1
item1, item2
item1, item2, item3
item1, item2, item3, item4 ...
```

What is happening is this:

```
item1,
item1, item2,
item1, item2, item3,
item1, item2, item3, item4 ...
```

Here is my code:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of record.referrerItemList; let i=index">
    <span *ngIf="i <= 3">{{item}}</span><span class="list-format" *ngIf="i < 3">&#44;&nbsp;</span>
    <span *ngIf="(i > 3) && (i < 5)" class="hellip-format">&hellip;</span>
</span>
```

Here is some list results:

```
Item1,  Item2,  Item3,  Item4 …
Item1, 
Item1,  Item2,  Item3,  Item4 …
Item1,  Item2,
```

Comment: I don't really see any difference between *what you're trying to do* and *what's happening*. Please specifically point out what's the difference. Would also be really helpful if you could post some code from your Component as well.

Comment: @Sidd see the commas at the end of each line at the top well I don't want them in see the difference between the two blocks?

Comment: how the list looks like, please share

Comment: is it like this `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a little change should work, in place of `i < 3` `i!=record.referrerItemList.length-1` will work because only the last one you don't want the comma.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of record.referrerItemList; let i=index">
    <span *ngIf="i <= 3">{{item}}</span><span class="list-format" *ngIf="i!=record.referrerItemList.length-1">&#44;&nbsp;</span>
    <span *ngIf="(i > 3) && (i < 5)" class="hellip-format">&hellip;</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Sorry this solution doesn't meet the requirements to the question.

Comment: This is the results I get with this logic:
Item1,  Item2,  Item3,  Item4,  ,  … ,  ,  , 

Item1

Item1,  Item2,  Item3,  Item4,  …

Answer (score 4):

You can use `*ngFor`'s `last` exported value to avoid adding the comma to the last element:

```
<span *ngFor="let item of record.referrerItemList; let i=index; let isLast=last">
    <span *ngIf="i <= 3">{{item}}</span><span class="list-format" *ngIf="!isLast && i < 3">&#44;&nbsp;</span>
    <span *ngIf="(i > 3) && (i < 5)" class="hellip-format">&hellip;</span>
</span>
```

For more info, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you seem to want to eliminate the final commas and have an ellipses if the length of the list exceeds four items.

You can use the `last` exported template variable to detect if you're on the last element.  This is the best condition to test for to prevent displaying a separator after the last element.

You can use the `SlicePipe` to display up to four items and in the last element detect if you need ellipses because the length of the source array is greater than four.

The behavior in the example will not display ellipses if there are only four items in the list.  You can change it if you want.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of record.referrerItemList | slice:0:4; let $last=last">
    {{item}}
    <span *ngIf="!$last; LastElem" class="list-format">&#44;&nbsp;</span>
    <ng-template #LastElem>
        <span *ngIf="record.referrerItemList.length > 4" class="hellip-format">
            &hellip;
        </span>
    </ng-template>
</span>
```

Comment: This solution does also works amended this comment. Thanks